# How can I make my function reference all the cells in my column that are being used instead of just having a broad function?

Tags: excel, function, worksheet

I have many formulas that reference a large list and at the time I just have them to 1000 to make it easy. There will come a day that I will surpass 1000 and I don't want to have to continuously update the function but at the same time I don't want to have an excessive range.
The following function is in cell CM4 and I have data in cells CM11:CM52 and each day one more gets added at the bottom. What kind of function could I use to just take the average of CM11:CM52 that will reference CM11:CM53 tomorrow and so on and so on?
The following formula is a simple one that is in my worksheet:
=AVERAGE(CM11:CM1000)

Comment: Have you thought of using a table?

Comment: I wasn't hoping to add anything more to the file (due to size) and was hoping to find an equation of some sort that I could just put into each cell.  @Enigmativity

Comment: Changing an existing set of cells to a table doesn't change the size of the spreadsheet much at all. I just did a test and had a spreadsheet change from 64kB to 65kB by adding a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many formulas do not have a cost to using full column references.  `AVERAGE()` is one of them so there is no problem using

```
=AVERAGE(A:A)
```

Or if you want to start on a certain row:

```
=AVERAGE(CM11:CM1048576)
```

For those formulas that do matter ie Array Types then we can make it dynamic with INDEX/MATCH

```
=AVERAGE(CM11:INDEX(CM:CM,MATCH(1E+99,CM:CM))
```

If the column in question is text then use `"zzz"` instead of `1E+99`

Comment: This works great, and I'll accept it. I was just curious as to why my excel has me correct the formula to "E1+99" instead of "1E+99". Also could you help me out and explain the "zzz"/ "1E+99" I have never seen that before and love to learn more :)

Comment: `"zzz"` looks for the last string and `1E+99` looks for the last number.  As to why yours changed, I don't have clue outside of it may be a local setting.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding your data to a table (insert>table). This will allow the formulas to update automatically.

Comment: I wasn't hoping to add anything more to the file (due to size) and was hoping to find an equation of some sort that I could just put into each cell.